# rectangle-insert in Emacs 24.4

Tags: emacs24.4, rectangle

Emacs 24.3 had a nice way of inserting text into rectangles:

1. Select rectangle.
2. `C-x r t` `<string-to-be-inserted>` `RET`

This doesn't seem to work in Emacs 24.4. I tried `rectangle-mark-mode` using `C-x SPC`. I could managed to insert a yanked rectangle, but how does one insert fresh text into the rectangle?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm on Emacs 24.4 and `C-x r t` works fine for me for inserting fresh text. Start Emacs via `emacs -Q` (which will keep your personal configuration from being loaded) and try again. Does it work?

Comment: @itsjeyd... thanks! emacs -q seems to have the keys working fine... I wonder what has been causing issues in my .emacs file. Nevertheless, I would be interested to know how it could be done through `rectangle-mark-mode`.

Comment: `rectangle-mark-mode` is a fairly young feature; it was introduced in Emacs 24.4. The NEWS file says: "New command `C-x SPC` (`rectangle-mark-mode`) makes a rectangular region. Most commands are still unaware of it, but kill/yank do work on the rectangle." Based on this I assume what you are trying to do is not possible (yet) with `rectangle-mark-mode`. You might want to look into `cua-mode` (built-in) or [`multiple-cursors`](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el).

Comment: As for debugging your `.emacs` file, the following method can help you identify problematic code quickly: **Recursively bisect** your `.emacs`: Comment out half of it and restart Emacs. If you can reproduce the problem, the code that's causing it is in the portion of your init-file that's *not* commented out (and vice versa). Repeat the process for the portion of the code that you know is causing the issue: Comment out half of it, restart, check for problem. Keep going until you've narrowed the problem down to a few lines; this shouldn't take too long.

Comment: (contd.) If you can't figure out *why* the code you've isolated is causing the issue, add it to your question so we can have a look at it.

Comment: @deejay What happens when you try out the following: (1) `C-h k C-x r t` (2) *Select some region in editable buffer* `M-x string-rectangle abc RET`? (1) should return description of that binding which should be `string-rectangle`. (2) even if the binding is messed up, this `M-x` approach should work. Knowing the outcome of (1) and (2) for you will help debug if your init messed up the binding or the core `string-rectangle` function.

Comment: @deejay You should investigate why `C-x r t` is not working for you instead of averting it by using `C-x SPC`. The debugging process will teach you skills that will be useful in fixing stuff caused by init. That usually happens if init is copied from another user.

Comment: @kaushalmodi (1) `C-h k C-x r t` gives: `C-x r t is undefined`. No hopes there... :( (2) `M-x string-rectangle RET abc RET` works as expected. It does not return the description of the binding associated (unusually...). So, I guess something is wrong with the binding. I will follow the method suggested by @itsjeyd to debug my init. Thanks, nevertheless.

Comment: @itsjeyd turns out (using your approach) that `(require 'discover)\n(global-discover-mode 1)` is the cause of the problem. I have commented it out in my current config... I wonder why this would cause any issue, though. I added it to learn the features of dired faster.

Comment: @deejay Can't reproduce the problem, sorry. It does, however, seem to affect a number of people: https://github.com/mickeynp/discover.el/issues/14 -- You might want to subscribe to that issue so you'll be notified about progress.

Comment: @itsjeyd Thanks for the link. BTW, I hope you did not take the `\n` literally? I meant to put a line change there, but comments space won't allow that.

Comment: @deejay No, I didn't :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`C-x r t` should still work in 24.4 just as in 24.3.

You can get the same functionality from `C-x SPC` by hitting `C-t` after you've selected the rectangle of interest.

Comment: Excellent! That works out of the box! Thanks dude!